# Ajax Contact Form Problems - No email being sent

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, contacts

Sorry for being a noob but I'm trying my best. I've done and read everything I could find and I have never got this to work. Would really appreciate the help. The form id matches in the html and javascript. The PHP is linked in the Javascript and I have the javascript linked in the head of my html. What am I missing? I've tried other codes I found online as well and nothing..  The issue is that no email ever gets sent through. If you hit send the page reloads and thats it.

```
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-noscript.css" />
    </noscript>


<!-- Contact Form-->
            <div class="content style4 featured">
            <div class="container small">
                <form id="contact" form method="post">
                    <div class="row half">
                        <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
                        <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row half">
                        <div class="12u"><textarea name="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">
                            <ul class="actions">
                                <li><input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
                                <li><input type="reset" class="button alt" value="Clear Form" /></li>
<p class="success" style="display:none">Your message has been sent successfully.</p>
                                <p class="error" style="display:none">E-mail must be valid and message must be longer than 100 characters.</p>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['text']) &&      filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
  if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
  exit;
}
}

  //send email
  mail( "test@gmail.com", "Contact Form: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['text'], "From:" .      $_POST['email'] );

}
?>
```

JS

```
     $('#contact').submit(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
 var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "mail.php",
        data : dataString,
        cache : false,
        success : function() {              
                $("#contact").fadeOut(300);
                                    $("#notice").fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
   return false;
 });
```

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly is the problem though?

Comment: You're including jQuery twice; any reason for that?

Comment: Sorry I edited the post. The issue is that no email ever gets sent through. If you hit send the page reloads and thats it. Which Jquery  code is being repeated?

Comment: If made all of the requested changes in the code above as well as on the server side and the page just reloads and I never receive an email. Anymore ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your js code run before jQuery has been loaded. Try to include jQuery before other js files:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dropotron.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact.js"></script>
```

By the way, you just need to include jQuery once, not twice.

Comment: Thanks Ill try both of these. Is one Jquery code better then another to keep? 1.10.1.min or query-migrate-1.2.1..?

Comment: You just need to remove the first included `jQuery` link, `CDN` is always better :)

Comment: Okay I've implemented both answered and still nothing. The screen flashes/reloads page and I never receive an email. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea has a `name="message"` whereas you are looking for `isset($_POST['text'])` in the submission handler code

Comment: Okay I've implemented both answered and still nothing. The screen flashes/reloads page and I never receive an email.

Comment: Sorry stupid question. I tried what you said and no emails are coming through.

Comment: Looking at your PHP code, you are attempting to get the value of the user's message from `$_POST['text']`. However, your HTML defines the textarea where the user can type as `<textarea name="message"..`. The way you have it written now, everything the user types will be found in `$_POST['message']` instead of `$_POST['text']`. Change the `textarea`'s `name` field to `text`, making it `<textarea name="text"..`

Comment: Okay it should be the way your asking in the code above correct?

Comment: Change its reference in the javascript code too: currently attempts to get data from the `message` field, which doesn't exist: `var message = $("#message").val();`